# Efficient finding of string mismatches in large lists

Tags: python, string, performance, comparison

I am iterating over large lists of strings to find similar strings (with several mismatches). The following code works but takes ~20 min, whereas my goal is for it to complete in under 5 min. Is there a more efficient way to do this? What part of this code is most limiting?

I have `k=10`, `mism=3`, `seq` is a string consisting of characters A, T, C, and G. Each `pattern` and `kmer` is k characters long.
I've generated lists of `patterns` of length 4**k (~1 million), and `kmers` of length len(seq)-k+1 (~300). `frequent` is a dictionary.

The test iteration takes less that a minute:

```
for i in range (0,4**k):
    for j in range(0,len(kmers)):
        pass
```

Here's the real calculation that I need to make more efficient:

```
for pattern in patterns:
    for kmer in kmers:
        mism_counter=0
        for j in range(0,k):
            if not kmer[j]==pattern[j] : mism_counter+=1
        if mism_counter <= mism :
            if pattern in frequent:
                frequent[pattern] += 1
            else:
                frequent[pattern] = 1
```

I tried wikipedia's `hamming_distance` function instead of my per-character comparison, and also tried to remove dictionary and just dump `pattern`'s into a list for further processing. None of this improved performance of the loops. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You have a third loop: `for j in range(k)`; that makes an additional 10 loops per outer loops. 10 times 'less than a minute' is still nearly 10 minutes, plus the `if` tests and dictionary access.

Comment: @MartijnPieters doesn't removing that for loop decrease the time from O(n^3) to O(n^2)?

Comment: @Dunno: 3rd loop: k=10; 1st loop: 4**k (~1e6)

Comment: where is `seq` in the code?

Comment: Also, can the last `if` be moved to the first loop (after `for kmer` finishes)?

Comment: thanks everybody for the helpful ideas. i ended up rethinking the algorithm so i was able to avoid these massive iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should save half the time ;-)

```
for pattern in patterns:
    for kmer in kmers:
        mism_counter=0
        for j in range(0,k):
            if kmer[j] != pattern[j] : 
                mism_counter+=1
                if mism_counter > misn:
                    break
        else:
            if pattern in frequent:
                frequent[pattern] += 1
            else:
                frequent[pattern] = 1
```

You have to do two things to make this really fast:

- Compress the data so your program does less work. You don't have to represent GTAC as ascii letters (7 bit each), instead 2 bit per letter are enough.
- Built a search trie from the patterns to speed up the comparison. Your search with allowed mismatches basically blows up the amount of pattern you have. You can have a trie with extra edges that allow a number of mismatches, but this essentially makes your search set huge.